# Django model-form-view connection

Tags: python, django, django-models, beautifulsoup, django-forms

I am trying to **scrape** datas from a website. Here is my models.py  `

```
from django.db import models
from .utils import get_link_data 
from .forms import AddLinkForm

class Link(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
price = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    name, price, image = get_link_data(AddLinkForm.url)
    self.name = name
    self.price = price
    self.image = image

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms


class AddLinkForm(forms.Form):
      url = forms.URLField()
```

And my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Link
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from .forms import AddLinkForm


def home_view(request):

form = AddLinkForm(request.POST or None)

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
form = AddLinkForm()
qs = Link.objects.all()
items_no = qs.count()


context = {
    'qs': qs,
    'items_no': items_no,
    'form': form,
}

return render(request, 'links/main.html', context)


class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
          model = Link
          template_name = 'links/details.html'
```

`

I have to change form.save() I guess, but how will I save the form after I change it and get the url from view? I dont want 'url' in my db so I didnt add it to my model.

Comment: I haven't seen save method in Form class its available in ModelForm.
I would try:

1. Install BeautifulSoup
2. Scrape url on form.is_valid()
3. Create Link object with scraped data.

Comment: maybe try:
`name, price, image = get_link_data(form.cleaned_data['url'])` on `form.is_valid()`
then `Link.objects.create(name=name, price=price, image=image)`

Comment: yes I did it like that sir, I forgot to update. thank you so much.